# MongoClient retorna vazio ao selecionar uma Collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-csharp

Estou usando o **MongoDb** **Atlas** com banco,e o **MongoDbDriver** para fazer a conexão, porém ao selecionar minha ***collection*** ele retorna vazio ao invés de retornar os dados da coleção.

***Minha conexão:***

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var connectionString = "mongodb+srv://<meu_usuario>:<minha_senha>@cluster0-kuyah.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true";
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

            var users = client.GetDatabase("WebApi").GetCollection<User>("usuario");

            var resultado = users.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

***Minha Model***

```
    public class User
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("nome")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("password")]
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
```